# Laravel 4 - Payment System Architecture

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, laravel, laravel-4

That will be a little hard do explain, but let me try:

I'm building an online store using Laravel 4 and now I have to create the payment methods and they might be completely different from each other and for each one of them I'll have to build a different number of pages (views), wich could be, as examples:

**Credit Card**

- Get the credit card data (to, first, create a token).
- Nice! It was accepted by the company and your token was created, would you really like to pay?
- It was paid, thanks!

**Credit Card**

- Get the debit card data.
- It was paid, thanks!

**Paypal**

- Jump to paypal site and wait for it to get back.

**Stripe**

- Gosh, we still doesn't have it in Brazil. :(

**Billet (Banking)** I think this is something we only have in Brazil. It's is a document (like a bill or a fracture, here's an example: [Billet](http://www.boletobancario.com/onlinedemo/samples/boletoCustom.jsp)) you can print at home (it has a barcode) and pay at your bank (online or in person). Payment is received in our bank account a couple of days after payment, so there's nothing we can do, just show the document and wait for a payment that may never happen:

- Just open a new window with it, customer may print it or not.

And, of course, for each step there might be decisions to make, problems, error messages, retries in case of errors (credit card may say "try again" and I must ask the user if he wants to do it).

So how would you achitecture this, in terms of (mainly) **views**, controllers and services (or repositories or libraries...), the way we can at anytime add more payment methods to the list. Are there any Design Patterns (to add to the Repository Pattern) wich would help to design this kind of interaction?

Comment: not an answer at all, but by the way - maybe you can tailor [Omnipay](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay) for your needs? Regards,

Comment: Omnipay does the interaction between your site and the Payment gateways, but it will not help you design the user interaction with your site (views & controllers), wich is the harderst to me at the moment. Because I'm trying to make those payment methods to be 'pluggable'. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I think [payum](https://github.com/Payum) does what you need. It does not have an integration with Laravel4 framework. but for the rest it would be good starting point. Check symfony [sandbox](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com) for more examples.

Ask any questions you may have, I am author of the lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the request in a queue you can use Command pattern.

As per my understanding in this scenario after getting the credit and debit card detail we will swipe then we will jump paypal site then we will have the Billet these are sequence activity or these are request queue here we can use Command pattern and for the different pages of your credit card ,debit card etc we can use factory class to get the instance of credit and debit cards etc.

Modifications are welcomed.